# Why do I get empty lists when listing files/folders in a folder using API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I've just created a folder "import" in sharepoint, where I've created :

- 1 emtpy folder "testdir"
- 2 emtpy files "test1.csv" and "test2.csv".

When I query this "import" folder through API, I get a valid response but which contains an empty list ("value":[]) :

[https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/mypath/import')/Folders](https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/mysite/mypath/import%27)/Folders)

```
{"odata.metadata":"https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Folders1","value":[]}
```

[https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/mypath/import')/Files](https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/mysite/mypath/import%27)/Files)

```
{"odata.metadata":"https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Files12","value":[]}
```

What am I missing here ? Why can't I see my "testdir" folder and my 2 test.csv files ?

Would it be possible I have different permissions in API compared to web IHM ? (no directory listing permissions in API ?) for security reason ?

UPDATE : As an additional, I tried this after creating an empty file in test dir :

[https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/mypath/import/testdir')/Files](https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/mysite/mypath/import/testdir%27)/Files)

And I get :

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024894, System.IO.FileNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value":"Fichier introuvable."}}}
```

What is happening here ? Is there a delay before I can query newly created folders/files ? Is there a "commit" command in sharepoint to create folder/files in sharepoint ?

Comment: In SharePoint commit concept exists only if versioning is enabled on document library, however "uncommitted" files are always visible to creator user. Are you sure your using same user in web page interface and in REST API calls?
In your URL, is "mypath" the name of a document library?

Comment: Hi, I've just asked essentially the identical question in StackOverflow so I wondered if the answer to this question had ever surfaced?